# How to remove last character from every line of string using php?

Tags: php, string, substr

I would like to remove last character from a word.
I have a file with the words:

```
hello.
world
welcome.
home..
how.
are.
you
any
thing.
else.
```

I am trying to remove the `.` from the end of each line.
For some reason my code removes the dot only from the last world `else` but leaves the rest as is.

Here is my code:

```
$words = file('words.txt');

foreach($words as $word) 
{
    echo substr($word, 0, -1);
    echo "<br />";
}
```

Does any one know how can i fix this?

Answer (score 1):

That's because last symbol in each line is a linebreak. Do `trim` before doing `substr`:

```
$words = file('words.txt');

foreach($words as $word) 
{
    echo substr(trim($word), 0, -1);   // here we go
    echo "<br />";
}
```

Or add [second argument](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php#refsect1-function.file-parameters) to `file` call:

```
$words = file('words.txt', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);

foreach($words as $word) 
{
    echo substr($word, 0, -1);
    echo "<br />";
}
```

Comment: hello u_mulder, Thanks for the answer. I tried your first code and it worked, but removed also the last character that is not a dot. i changed:    echo substr(trim($word), 0, -1) to echo rtrim(trim($word), "."); and now it works perfectly. Thank you

Comment: have tried the second way - also works great with rtrim instead of substr. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

*One-line* solution using `file_get_contents` and `preg_replace` functions:

```
$new_contents = preg_replace("/(\w+)\.*([\r\n]|$)/", "$1</br>", file_get_contents("words.txt"));
echo $new_contents;
```

The output:

```
hello

world

welcome

home

how

are

you

any

thing

else
```

Comment: Thank you. Works very well.